# When to use Temporary SQL Tables vs DataTables

Tags: c#, sql-server

I don't know whether it is better to use temporary tables in SQL Server or use the DataTable in C# for a report. Here is the scope of the report: it will be copied into a workbook with about 10 worksheets - each worksheet containing about 1000 rows and about 30 columns so it's a lot of data.  There is some guidance out there but I could not find anything specific regarding the amount of data that is too much for a DataTable. According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx, 16M rows but my data set seems unwieldy considering the number of columns I have.  Plus, I will either have to make multiple SQL queries to collect the data in my report or try to write a stored procedure in SQL to collect that data.  How do I figure out this quandary?

Comment: "How do I figure out this quandary?" - use gut feeling and choose the most _understandable_ and _maintainable_ solution. If it turns out to be too slow you can try something else. The most important part it is to get something _working correctly_ and then worry about the speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My rule of thumb is that if it can be processed on the database server, it probably should.  Keep in mind, no matter how efficient your C# code is, SQL Server will mostly likely to it faster and more efficiently, after all it was designed for data manipulation.

There is no shame in using #temp tables.  They maintain stats, can be indexed, and/or manipulated.  One recent example, a developer create an admittedly elegant query using cte, the performance was 12-14 seconds vs mine at 1 second using #temps.

Now, one carefully structured stored procedure could produce and return the 10 data-sets for your worksheets.  If you are using a product like SpreadSheetLight (there are many options available), it becomes a small matter of passing the results and creating the tabs (no cell level looping... unless you want or need to).

I would also like to add, you can dramatically reduce the number of touch points and better enforce the business logic by making SQL Server do the heavy lifting.  For example, a client introduced a 6W risk rating, which was essentially a 6.5.   HUNDREDS of legacy reports had to be updated, while I only had to add the 6W into my mapping table.

Comment: +1 -- Just last week I had the experience of refactoring a bunch of Common Table Expressions into a couple of connection-scoped #temp tables. I gained a factor of about fifty in performance, and reduced contention on my busy SQL Server.  The ability to index the big temp table was very helpful in that.

Comment: @OllieJones It's a great feeling when you get results like that.  Years ago, what would take 14 hours on the mainframe took 6 minutes in VFP on a PC.  If Audit knew what I was doing, they would have yanked my network connection from the wall.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of missing context here - how is this report going to be accessed and run? Is this going to run as a scripted event every day?

Have you considered SSRS?

In my opinion it's best to abstract away your business logic by creating Views or Stored Procedures in the database. Stored Procedures would probably be the way to go but it really depends on your specific environment. Then you can point whatever tools you want to use at the database object. This has several advantages:

- if you end up having different versions or different formats of the report, and your logic ever changes, you can update the logic in one place rather than many.
- your code is simpler and cleaner, typically:

`select v.col1, v.col2, v.col3
from MY_VIEW v
where v.date between @startdate and @enddate`

I assume your 10 spreadsheets are going to be something like

Summary Page | Department 1 | Department 2 | ...

So you could make a generalized View or SP, create a master spreadsheet linked to the db object that pulls all the relevant data from SQL, and use Pivot Tables or filters or whatever else you want, and use that to generate your copies that get sent out.

But before going to all that trouble, I would make sure that SSRS is not an option, because if you can use that, it has a lot of baked in functionality that would make your life easier (export to Excel, automatic date parameters, scheduled execution, email subscriptions, etc).

Comment: This is a daily report with the last 30 days activity on there.  You are right in your assumptions about the spreadsheets.  Thank you for your thoughts.  I will look more in detail into SSRS.  I didn't realize that it had so much integrated functionality.